# How to dispatch event on object method call in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I've tried to dispatch an event on a method call like this:

```
Group.remove(obj).dispatchEvent({type:'remove', message:'Object removed'});
```

and listen to it on the canvas, like this:

```
document.getElementById('threeCanvas').addEventListener('remove', onObjRemove, false);
function onObjRemove(event){ console.log(event)}
```

but nothing happens...
On the page of [Three.js Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D) says that [Three.js EventDispatcher](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/EventDispatcher) methods are available. Sooo what am I doing wrong?

r98

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`THREE.EventDispatcher` has nothing to do with DOM events. It just enables an event-driven API on custom JavaScript objects. The following example from the [github repository](https://github.com/mrdoob/eventdispatcher.js) might help to better understand this:

```
function Car() {

    this.start = function () {

        this.dispatchEvent( { type: 'start', message: 'vroom vroom!' } );

    };

}

Object.assign( Car.prototype, EventDispatcher.prototype );

// Using events

var car = new Car();

car.addEventListener( 'start', function ( event ) {

    alert( event.message );

} );

car.start();
```

`three.js R99`

Comment: That did the trick, listening on the Group solved my issues. Anyways, just for sake of curiosity, is there any way to send events from three.js to DOM ?

Comment: At stackoverflow, it's better to ask a new question in a new thread.